# Angle increment spiral in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, coding-style

[image]

What method cold I use to obtain a Plot similar to the one in the picture?

Comment: Have you already tried to plot something yourself? Generally you’ll get more bites if you actually tried something...posting the code you used aswell is helpful.

Comment: Related: [Pentagonal spiral in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125007/731). The figure you are asking for is actually produced in the question text of [Filling Space with Pursuit Polygons](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145050/731), although the question is not really about this figure.

Comment: see also [Drawing the Pursuit curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/177209/34893).

Answer (score 20):

Here is an adaptation of my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125012/731):

```
steps = Table[{r, 1.005 (2 Pi/4)}, {r, 1, 25, 0.2}];
Graphics[{Black, Line@AnglePath[steps]}, Background -> White]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The spiral tendency is controlled by the value `1.005` in the code, and the spacing between the lines is controlled by the value `0.2`.

Answer (score 11):

Not really an answer, since this isn't a single line but I thought it was interesting so I'll post it.

```
rc = Rectangle[];
center = {0.5, 0.5};
transforms = Table[
    ScalingTransform[{x, x}, center] @* RotationTransform[(1 + -x) * Pi / 4, center],
    {x, 1, 0.025, -0.025}
];
Graphics @ {EdgeForm @ Black, FaceForm @ None, GeometricTransformation[rc, transforms]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Um, I like spirals. So as @C.E. points out, `AnglePath` is a useful function.

```
 Manipulate[
    Graphics[{Thick,
       MapIndexed[{ColorData[cs, (#2[[1]]*d)^e], Line[#]} &,
          Partition[AnglePath[Table[{r, a*Degree}, {r, 0, 1., d}]], 2, 1]]
    }, Background -> Black, ImageSize -> 500],
    {{d, 0.01, "Step Increment"}, 0.002, 0.02, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{a, 119., "Angle Increment (Degree)"}, 1., 180., Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{e, 1.5, "Colour Exponent"}, 0.1, 3.0, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {{cs, "SandyTerrain", "Colour Scheme"}, ColorData["Gradients"]}
 ]
```

[image: spirals!]

Comment: There is an interesting optical illusion when scrolling this figure up and down quickly!