# Dog-Owner problem(pursuit curve)

Tags: differential-equations

A dog in the coordinate system starts from the origin along the x-axis with vk=1m/s speed. The owner starts from the (0,1) point running towards the direction of the dog with vg=2m/s speed.Show the path of the dog and owner(blue and red) on the t=[0,0.51] interval.

This is the graph that i need to get:
[image]

Here is my take on it,but for some reason the path of the owner won't reach the dog on t=[0,0.51] in my case.

```
{kutyax, kutyay, gazdaq, gazdaz} = 
 NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == 1, y'[t] == 0, 
   z'[t] == 2*(x[t] - z[t])/Sqrt[(x[t] - z[t])^2 + (y[t] - q[t])^2], 
   q'[t] == 2*(y[t] - q[t])/Sqrt[(x[t] - z[t])^2 + (y[t] - q[t])^2], 
   x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, q[0] == 1}, {x, y, z, q}, {t, 0, 
   0.51}]
Show[ParametricPlot[{kutyax[t], kutyay[t]}, {t, 0, 0.51}, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue], 
 ParametricPlot[{gazdaq[t], gazdaz[t]}, {t, 0, 0.51}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

And here is my graph:
[image]

Comment: Similar to this:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187009/cat-catch-mouse-application-of-differentials-equations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expectation dog reaches owner at `t=.51` seems to be wrong!

I modified `NDSolve` with a `WhenEvent`

```
{kutyax, kutyay, gazdaq, gazdaz} =NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == 1, y'[t] == 0,z'[t] == 2*(x[t] - z[t])/Sqrt[(x[t] - z[t])^2 + (y[t] - q[t])^2], q'[t] == 2*(y[t] - q[t])/Sqrt[(x[t] - z[t])^2 + (y[t] - q[t])^2],x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, q[0] == 1
, WhenEvent[(x[t] - z[t])^2 + (y[t] - q[t])^2 == 0.0001 ,  "StopIntegration"]}, {x, y, z, q}, {t, 0, 1}]
tsim = kutyax["Domain"][[1, 2]]  
(*0.656669*)
```

dog reaches owner at `t=.66`!

```
Show[{ParametricPlot[{kutyax[t], kutyay[t]}, {t, 0, tsim}, PlotStyle -> Blue],ParametricPlot[{gazdaq[t], gazdaz[t]}, {t, 0, tsim}, PlotStyle -> Red]}, PlotRange-> All]
```

[image]