# How to draw random colorfull domains in a plane?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, random, generative-art, version-7

I'm trying to produce some graphics like the one shown below, with a few adjustable parameters to change the number and size of cells.  The cells positions, sizes and colors should all be random (size between some min and max values):

[image]

The whole graphics should be shown inside a simple square, just for convenience for exportation.

My problem is that I really don't know how to start this, since there are many random vertices and straight lines dividing the domains.  This is a kind of Mathematica programming problem that I'm unable to do by myself alone.  :-(

I could start with a set of random points in a plane, using this code:

```
RandomPoints = 
  Table[{RandomReal[{-10, 10}], RandomReal[{-10, 10}]}, {n, 1, 50}];

ListPlot[RandomPoints,
 Axes -> False,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> None,
 AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

But then, how to draw lines between these points, without any crossing, so we could get nice looking cells?

So I need suggestions.  I don't need anything fancy, just the simplest tricks that I could study and understand.  I'm working on **Mathematica 7**, and I can't change the computer for a newer version of Mathematica yet.

Comment: See `VoronoiMesh` documentation:  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VoronoiMesh.html and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225510/drawing-a-realistic-voronoimesh.

Comment: In version 7 you should have access to the [``ComputationalGeometry` ``](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ComputationalGeometry/guide/ComputationalGeometryPackage.html) package, which contained [`VoronoiDiagram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ComputationalGeometry/ref/VoronoiDiagram.html) and [`DiagramPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ComputationalGeometry/ref/DiagramPlot.html).

Comment: @MarcoB, I loaded the package. But then l’m still unable to draw some tesellation. I need an exemple.

Comment: Perhaps you could make use of the free cloud version, which is much more capable than version 7. Most people no longer have access to version 7, so answers are likely to be based on guesswork about what works and what doesn't in v7.

Comment: essentially a duplicate of [How can I draw such faceted triangle patterns?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163935/how-can-i-draw-such-faceted-triangle-patterns).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### ListDensityPlot

```
Normal[ListDensityPlot[RandomReal[10, {100, 3}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 0, ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> False]] /. 
 Polygon[x_, ___] :> {Hue@RandomReal[], EdgeForm[Gray],Polygon[x]}
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
ListDensityPlot[RandomReal[10, {100, 3}], InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> "Pastel"]
```

[image]

#### ListContourPlot

```
Normal[ListContourPlot[RandomReal[10, {100, 3}], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 0, ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> False]] /. 
 Polygon[x_, ___] :> {Hue@RandomReal[], EdgeForm[Gray], Polygon[x]}
```

[image]

An example with less randomness:  randomly perturbed hexagons:

```
SeedRandom[1]
lst = Join @@ Array[{RandomReal[.3] + 3/2 #, 
      RandomReal[] + Sqrt[3] #2 + Mod[#, 2] Sqrt[3]/2, 
      RandomInteger[100]} &, {9, 9}];


Normal[ListContourPlot[lst, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
   ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> False]] /. 
 Polygon[x_, ___] :> {Hue@RandomReal[], EdgeForm[Gray], Polygon[x]}
```

[image]

#### DensityPlot + Nearest

```
SeedRandom[1]
nearestFunction = First @* Nearest[Table[RandomInteger[10, 2] -> u, {u, 120}]];

ContourPlot[nearestFunction[{x, y}], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
 PlotPoints -> 90, Contours -> 50, ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", 
 Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: @Cham, `Hue @ RandomReal[]` should work in v7.

Comment: Well, I need some help for the colors in my solution.  I would like to get rid of that part before @@@pts, which I really don't understand.

Comment: These colors are very agressive.  Could you change them for something more "pastel-like", like the image I've shown in my question?

Comment: Also, your last example shows cells that all have 6 sides (a few have 5).  It should be more random than that.

Comment: does `ListDensityPlot[RandomReal[10, {100, 3}], InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> "Pastel"]` work in v7?

Comment: Yes, it works nicely!

Comment: That last solution of yours appears to be really great!  It's much easier to understand to me, and it's now very easy to change the colors!  I suggest that your present it as a third solution and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks @Cham @kglr, the `ListContourPlot` is a good idea.

I think we can also does not change the original points in the plane,so we append the three coordinate with different number. Here we just use {1,2,...,n}

And we use `ContourShading` to add the colors.

The final result is just the same as `VoronoiMesh`!

```
SeedRandom[123];
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 2}];
pts3 = MapIndexed[Join, pts];
ListContourPlot[pts3, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
 ContourShading -> Table[CMYKColor[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3]], {i, 50}], 
 BoundaryStyle -> White, Axes -> False, Frame -> False]
Show[%, ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> White]]
```

**Compare the 2D and 3D versions.**

```
ListPlot3D[pts3, InterpolationOrder -> 0, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 Mesh -> None, Axes -> None, ViewPoint -> {0.54, -1.49, 2.98}, 
 ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"]
```

[image]

Comment: `MapIndexed[Flatten[{##}] &, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 2}]]`

Answer (score 4):

Well, I just found a nice trick, but it's not fully satisfying yet, since the cell color isn't random.  How can I modify this code to get random colors in all cells?

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 2}];

f[{x_, y_}] := x^2 - y^2 (* I don't understand the color part ! *)

ListContourPlot[Function[{x, y}, {x, y, f[{x, y}]}] @@@pts,
  Mesh -> All,
  MeshStyle -> Thick,
  InterpolationOrder -> 0,
  Axes -> False,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> None,
  AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: I could replace the function x^2 - y^2 with something like RandomReal[{-1, 1}], which gives some random variations in colors, but it's always in shades of blue.  I don't understand this part.